# Search MySql database for a HTML link using PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have mysql table that contatins item_id and link columns the link column contains html tags and the actual link. now I want to search the database for a link that doesn't contain html tags what is the best way to do this in php?

Comment: Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easy answer depends on assumptions you can make based on what you know about the data.

If these links were inserted programmatically, and you trust your own code to create well-formed links, you can eliminate anything that includes the link closure.

```
SELECT mytable.item_id FROM mytable WHERE mytable.link NOT LIKE '%</a>%'
```

Answer (score 0):

you could concatenate the raw url with tags and search with this or use the like compare method from mysql

```
select * from urls where link like '%http://google.com%'
```